Issue with Displaying Data in Table Format on D365 F&O Copilot's SideCar
I am working on displaying my data in table formatI (I use Adpative Card for this) on D365 F&O Copilot's SideCar after creating a topic in Copilot Studio.
My YAML code is:
kind: AdaptiveDialog
beginDialog:
  kind: OnRecognizedIntent
  id: main
  intent:
    triggerQueries:
      - Table Format
  actions:
    - kind: SetVariable
      id: setVariable_E91nKn
      variable: Topic.ListData
      value: "{   \"endDate\": \"6/30/2024\",   \"isResponse\": true,   \"startDate\": \"6/1/2024\",   \"unpostedJournals\": [     {       \"Batch Number\": \"25136\",       \"Name\": \"GenJrn\",       \"Description\": \"General Journal\",       \"Date\": \"06/26/2024 00:00:00\"     },     {       \"Batch Number\": \"25139\",       \"Name\": \"IntJrn\",       \"Description\": \"Intercompany Journal\",       \"Date\": \"06/30/2024 00:00:00\"     },     {       \"Batch Number\": \"25140\",       \"Name\": \"IntJrn\",       \"Description\": \"Test description\",       \"Date\": \"06/10/2024 00:00:00\"     }   ] }"
    - kind: ParseValue
      id: 1nX2rj
      variable: Topic.parseListData
      valueType:
        kind: Record
        properties:
          endDate: String
          isResponse: Boolean
          startDate: String
          unpostedJournals:
            type:
              kind: Table
              properties:
                Batch Number: String
                Date: String
                Description: String
                Name: String
      value: =Topic.ListData
    - kind: SendActivity
      id: sendActivity_cLjUwq
      activity:
        attachments:
          - kind: AdaptiveCardTemplate
            cardContent: |-
              ={
               
                type: "AdaptiveCard",
                version: "1.3",
                body: [
                  {
                    type: "TextBlock",
                    text: "Unposted Journals",
                    weight: "Bolder",
                    size: "Medium"
                  },
                  {
                    type: "ColumnSet",
                    columns: [
                      {
                        type: "Column",
                        width: "stretch",
                        items: [
                          {
                            type: "TextBlock",
                            text: "Batch Number",
                            weight: "Bolder",
                            wrap: true
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        type: "Column",
                        width: "stretch",
                        items: [
                          {
                            type: "TextBlock",
                            text: "Name",
                            weight: "Bolder",
                            wrap: true
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        type: "Column",
                        width: "stretch",
                        items: [
                          {
                            type: "TextBlock",
                            text: "Description",
                            weight: "Bolder",
                            wrap: true
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        type: "Column",
                        width: "stretch",
                        items: [
                          {
                            type: "TextBlock",
                            text: "Date",
                            weight: "Bolder",
                            wrap: true
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    type: "Container",
                    items: 
                    ForAll(Topic.parseListData.unpostedJournals,
                        {
                        type: "ColumnSet",
                        data: "${unpostedJournals}",
                        columns: [
                          {
                            type: "Column",
                            width: "stretch",
                            items: [
                              {
                                type: "TextBlock",
                                text: 'Batch Number',
                                wrap: true
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            type: "Column",
                            width: "stretch",
                            items: [
                              {
                                type: "TextBlock",
                                text: Name,
                                wrap: true
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            type: "Column",
                            width: "stretch",
                            items: [
                              {
                                type: "TextBlock",
                                text: Description,
                                wrap: true
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            type: "Column",
                            width: "stretch",
                            items: [
                              {
                                type: "TextBlock",
                                text: Date,
                                wrap: true
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    
                 ) }
                ]
              }

After publishing this, when I entered "Table Format" (the question I asked in Copilot's SideCar), it returns an empty message instead of a table.
D365F&O Copilot's SideCar
Is there anyone who can help me understand why I am getting an empty message in response? Or can anyone tell me if there is a different way to get a table format via Copilot Studio?
